# how to display image files separately as a link retrieved from MySQL database using PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, image

I need to display data retrieved from `MySQL` in a table format(like a GUI) using `PHP` scripting, my data contains text and images, when ever an image retrieved from db the its altering my table format of presentation, so instead of displaying an image or attachment my page should display a `link` to the attachment instead of image my sample code is below, it fetches all the data from database

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>
              <td>$row[1]</td>
              <td>$row[2]</td>
              <td>$row[3]</td>
              <td>$row[4]</td>
              <td>$row[5]</td>
         </tr>";
}
```

Comment: Use `img` tag to display and image.

Comment: my code is displaying image but i concerned about the way of presenting data(table), so when ever there is image from the data that was fetched it should display a link to that image, if I press on link the image should be opened in a new tab

Answer (score 0):

Try this one suppose your img link coming in `$row[4]` variable then. Have a look

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>
              <td>$row[1]</td>
              <td>$row[2]</td>
              <td>$row[3]</td>
              <td><a href='".$row[4]."' target='_blank'>Show Image</a></td>
              <td>$row[5]</td>
              </tr>";
    }
```

Comment: it may contain text with image or only image or only text in any case if there is an image then only for the image a link should be displayed I can't figure where to add condition either at query level, then it limits the options so it does't work. some how I should get whether there is image if true display image as a `link`

Comment: plz `echo "<pre>"; print_r($row)` once and post here to better understanding.